Start of instantaneous hazard rate
I'm looking at survival of organizations, with survival in years. I want to produce an instantaneous hazard plot with a confidence interval. I first used pehaz from the muhaz package, but it doesn't provide an SE, so I switched to epi.insthaz from epiR. I noticed then that epi.insthaz produces an instantaneous hazard only from the first event onwards, while the outcome of pehaz starts at 0.

r_epi <- survfit(Surv(age, closing) ~ 1, dt)


epi.insthaz(r_epi)
   time n.risk n.event      sest      slow      supp        hest          hlow       hupp
1     1    503       1 0.9980119 0.9859173 0.9997208 0.001988072  3.510297e-04 0.01117419
2     2    495       3 0.9919634 0.9785617 0.9970001 0.006060606  2.063250e-03 0.01766538
3     3    473       5 0.9814775 0.9642673 0.9904395 0.010570825  4.523441e-03 0.02450394
4     4    450       3 0.9749343 0.9556402 0.9858982 0.006666667  2.269806e-03 0.01941499



pehaz(dt$age, dt$closing, width=1)
Cuts Defining the Bins:
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  
Hazard Estimate for Each Bin:
 [1] 0.000000000 0.002020202 0.006342495 0.011111111 0.007109005 0.015037594

The organizations I'm looking at have not been around for that long (most are left-censored by t=10), so it makes a visible difference whether the instantaneous hazard function starts at 0 or 1 (the first failure).

I also noticed that in KM plots produced by ggsurvfit the KM estimator starts at t=0, and if I add a CI it is zero for t=0.
r_epi %>% ggsurvfit() + add_confidence_interval()


Does it make sense to calculate an instantaneous hazard for t=0, and if so, how would you get its SE?
